# Spring @Transactional how manage the transactions

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions, spring-transactions

how Spring `@Transactional` manage the transactions. let's say below is the method example, if Database goes down then I observed `@Transactional` throws below error.. and it does not execute `writeStuff()`.. is this correct behavior of `@Transactional`s?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.05] [Error 1000] [SQLState 08S01] Login failure for Connection to
```

```java
  @Transactional(value = "txnMngr", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
    public void writeStuff() {

      // write something to your database
    }
```

here is my bean configuration

```xml
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <qualifier value="txnMngr"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Yes. How should anything be written if there is no datastore available?

Comment: @M.Deinum , I was assuming that, it should throw error when i call the jdbcTemplate.execute() but it is throwing on method writeStuff() level.

Comment: The @transactional eagerly gets a connection, that connection cannot be obtained hence an error.